# Stream radio from url with AVPlayer -> iPhone player controls not working

Tags: ios, avplayer, avaudiosession

I use AVPlayer to stream a live sound from a url.

It works perfectly except when my app is in background and I want to play or pause the iPhone player in the swipe-up menu (I dont know its exact name). The volume controls work, but not the play/pause controls.

I have been looking through SO and the internet for hours and cant figure it out.

Any help?

Here is the code (dont hesitate if you need any more code):

```
// Set AudioSession
NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

// Init player
self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
self.audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
[self.audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the remote controls in your app yourself. This is not handled by `AVPlayer`.

Want you need to read is [Remote Control Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html).

You need make some class the firs responder, like your root view controller. Make sure it is receiving al the event by calling `[self becomeFirstResponder]`. 
Then just implement the event handler for remote control events:

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)receivedEvent {

    if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
      switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {
         case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            [self playOrStop: nil];
            break;

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
            [self previousTrack: nil];
            break;

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
            [self nextTrack: nil];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```